# Why do I need to use the sigemptyset() function before the sigaddset()?

Tags: signals, posix

I was told that every time I want to use `sigset_t block_mask`, I also need to use the `sigemptyset()` function before I use `sigaddset()`. For example:

```
sigset_t block_mask;
sigemptyset(&block_mask);
sigaddset(&block_mask, SIGSEGV);
```

Why do I need to do it every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sigaddset` changes a single signal in the set, but leaves the information about all other signals unaffected.
Without `sigemptyset`, that other information would not have been initialized.

Think of a signal set as a bitmask, something like this:

```c
sigset_t block_mask;                int block_mask;
sigemptyset(&block_mask);           block_mask = 0;
sigaddset(&block_mask, SIGSEGV);    block_mask |= 1 << SIGSEGV;
```